# Passing function as parameter on hover doesn't work

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, hover

I would like to make text come up slowly when mouse is over those classes and it all worked but I wanted to delegate it to a function that seems to be wrong. What's the problem?

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    cambiarClasesDeProductosEnCelulares();

    $(".top-box, .middle-box, .bottom-box, .second-box, .third-box, .fourth-box").hover(aparicionDeTexto(800, 1250));
});

function aparicionDeTexto(duracionTexto, duracionOpacidad) { // ON HOVER, TEXT SHOULD COME UP SLOWLY
    $(this).find("p").css(
        "top", "20px", 
        "opacity", "0").animate({
        top: "0",
    }, {duration: duracionTexto, 
        queue: false}).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, duracionOpacidad);
}
```

It seems to be not responding to the event hover(). After page is ready, it fires it... why?

Comment: Inside the function, `this` refers to nothing, you need to pass it along when invoking the function.

Comment: I did it and didn't work. In stackoverflow I read that you don't have to send this as a parameter. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the document is ready, it will fire `aparicionDeTexto(800, 1250)` automatically. Since the function `aparicionDeTexto` returns nothing, your hover code above is the same thing as invoking the function first, and passing the return value of that function to `hover`.

```
var returnedValue = aparicionDeTexto(800, 1250); // which is undefined
$("...").hover(returnedValue);
```

What you want is for `aparicionDeTexto(800, 1250)` to *return a function* that hover **can call** whenever the hover event is received. One way to solve this is to modify the function `aparicionDeTexto` to return a function (i.e. closure) that does `$(this).find("p")...`. However, you need to be careful of the keyword `this` as it might not refer to the `this` that you intend it to be.

An alternative solution is to use JavaScript's [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method and not modify your existing `aparicionDeTexto` function.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Here's what you can do:

```
var box = $(".top-box, .middle-box, .bottom-box, .second-box, .third-box, .fourth-box");
box.hover(aparicionDeTexto.bind(box, 800, 1250));
```

The assumption here is that when you do `$(this).find("p")`, you are attempting to find all paragraph elements in the `box` element.

Comment: Wow thanks for the response! You could make it work. I didn't notice anything about what you said and now it's solved. Thanks brother!

Comment: And is there an option to make, in the second solution, a way to not find all paragraph elements in the box element and only the one that was hovered? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you achieve that by using CSS pseudo-classes. Replace `$(this).find("p")` with `$(this).find("p:hover")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate